# Solr - how to get children of parent documents where parents are filtered by multiple criteria?

Tags: solr

I have in solr documents that resemble the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "stationId-37246",
        "type": "station",
        "territory": "372",
        "genres":
        {
            "id": "genreId-37246-a4nm24kgsadvmdv4cgemt-20-372-ga",
            "type": "genre",
            "genre_type": "station",
            "genre_href": "3.1.1.11",
            "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "stationId-3724",
        "territory": "372",
        "type": "station",
        "genres":
        {
            "id": "genreId-3724-ep7tvwiiekl9ud8vewhjb-3-372-ga",
            "type": "genre",
            "genre_type": "station",
            "genre_href": "3.1.1",
            "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "stationId-37245",
        "territory": "372",
        "type": "station",
        "genres":
        {
            "id": "genreId-37245-4osajn644rg7p3jd8jqu8m-20-372-ga",
            "type": "genre",
            "genre_type": "station",
            "genre_href": "3.1.1.11",
            "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "odId-37248",
        "territory": "372",
        "type": "ondemand",
        "genres":
        {
            "id": "genreId-37248-y1wljbe9uus1m25yqie23s-122-372-ga",
            "type": "genre",
            "genre_type": "ondemand",
            "genre_href": "3.1.5.2",
            "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "stationId-44449",
        "territory": "444",
        "type": "station",
        "genres":
        {
            "id": "genreId-44449-y1wljbe9uus1m25yqie23s-122-372-ga",
            "type": "genre",
            "genre_type": "station",
            "genre_href": "3.1.5.4",
            "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
        }
    }
]
```

I need to be able to give a list of genres, for a particular territory and for a particular genre type.

For example I want to be able to get the list of genres, that are attached to parents that are in territory 372, and have the genre_type:station.

The above example should produce something like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "genreId-37246-a4nm24kgsadvmdv4cgemt-20-372-ga",
        "type": "genre",
        "genre_type": "station",
        "genre_href": "3.1.1.11",
        "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
    },
    {
        "id": "genreId-37245-4osajn644rg7p3jd8jqu8m-20-372-ga",
        "type": "genre",
        "genre_type": "station",
        "genre_href": "3.1.1.11",
        "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
    },
    {
        "id": "genreId-3724-ep7tvwiiekl9ud8vewhjb-3-372-ga",
        "type": "genre",
        "genre_type": "station",
        "genre_href": "3.1.1",
        "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
    }
]
```

But if I'd want the same type of genres, for territory 444 I'd get

```
{
    "id": "genreId-44449-y1wljbe9uus1m25yqie23s-122-372-ga",
    "type": "genre",
    "genre_type": "station",
    "genre_href": "3.1.5.4",
    "_nest_path_": "/genres#"
}
```

Any suggestions? I'm trying to do all kinds of voodoo, but I find the solr documentation site a bit difficult to comprehend. :\

So this returns correctly:

```
"params":
        {
            "q": "{!child of=\"+type: station\"}territory:372",
            "fq":
            [
                "genre_type: station",
                "type: genre"
            ],
        }
```

but this one throws the same error as below:

```
"params":
        {
            "q": "{!child of=\"+type: ondemand\"}territory:372",
            "fq":
            [
                "genre_type: ondemand",
                "type: genre"
            ],
        }
```

```
Parent query must not match any docs besides parent filter. Combine them as must (+) and must-not (-) clauses to find a problem doc. docID=50924
```

Comment: If I try: ```{!child of="type:station territory:372"}``` I get all sorts of things, and not just from that territory

Comment: Ok. So the following: `{!child of="+type: station"}+s_rpuid:372*` will give some almost good results, but also gives quite a few false positives.  Relying on the s_rpuid shouldn't be really an option, that's why I didn't include in my sample data.

Comment: but using `{!child of="+type: station"}territory:372` gives the error `Parent query must not match any docs besides parent filter. Combine them as must (+) and must-not (-) clauses to find a problem doc. docID=72403` - which I don't understand what it means

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for some reason, SOLR want's to be really sure about my intentions and I have to repeat mysef repeat myself:

```
{
    "params":
    {
        "q": "{!child of=+type:station}(territory:372 +type:station)",
        "fq":
        [
            "type: genre",
            "genre_type: station"
        ],
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "params":
    {
        "q": "{!child of=+type:ondemand}(territory:372 +type:ondemand)",
        "fq":
        [
            "type: genre",
            "genre_type: ondemand"
        ],
    }
}
```